# DB2 SQL error sqlcode=-104 sqlstate=42601

Tags: sql, db2

I am relatively new to DB2 but not to SQL. I am experiencing the below error when trying a `SELECT` statement while subtracting a few minutes from a `timestamp`:

```
SELECT * TCCAWZTXD.TCC_COIL_DEMODATA 
WHERE CURRENT_INSERTTIME  BETWEEN(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-5 minutes AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The error that I am experiencing is:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   SQLERRMC=TCCAWZTXD;SELECT*;, DRIVER=3.66.46

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Side note: you generally shouldn't be using `SELECT *`.  Explicitly list out the columns you're interested in.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You miss the `from` clause

```
SELECT *  from TCCAWZTXD.TCC_COIL_DEMODATA WHERE CURRENT_INSERTTIME  BETWEEN(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-5 minutes AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```